# How to compare for equality Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text and [Char]?

Tags: string, haskell, text, type-conversion, esqueleto

The `previousLogItem` data type returned by esqueleto contains [Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text-Internal-Lazy.html)

```
import           Data.Text.Lazy                        (pack)

previousLogItem <- select $ from $ \l -> do
        orderBy [desc (l ^. LogItemId)]
        limit 1
        return (l ^. LogItemTitle)
```

Later I tried to compare `previousLogItem` with `exampleCharList` by using:

```
[Value (pack currentWindowTitle)] == previousLogItem
```

But that does not work since the types still differ:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
                 with ‘Text’
  NB: ‘Text’ is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal’
      ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
        is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy’
    arising from a functional dependency between:
      constraint ‘Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql.SqlSelect
                    (SqlExpr (Value Text)) (Value Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text)’
        arising from a use of ‘select’
      instance ‘Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql.SqlSelect
                  (SqlExpr (Value a)) (Value a)’
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Couldn't match type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
                with ‘Text’
  NB: ‘Text’ is defined in ‘Data.Text.Internal’
    ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’
```

You're using the wrong kind of `Text`. Check your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the original question

Have you tried using `fromString` from the `IsString` class? `Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text` should be an instance of `IsString`

Old (useless) answer:

Use the `pack` function from `Data.Text.Lazy` to convert the `String` to `Text`

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text-Lazy.html

Comment: I forgot to mention but the pack I used is the one you mentioned, eg. from `Data.Text.Lazy`. So this is what I am doing and it is not working.

Comment: I tried [Value (fromStrict $ pack currentWindowTitle)] == previousLogItem but it still gives same error: Couldn't match type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text’ with ‘Text’

Comment: Using [Value (toStrict $ pack currentWindowTitle)] == previousLogItem is what worked in the end.